# Alphabet ordering random lists

Tags: lists, enumerate, makeindex

I am wanting to create a definition of terms and I will happily take any advice I can on doing this, what I am looking to do initially, this may be wrong, is to do something like 
\list{variable} Definition: ...
\list{class} Definition ....
 and have them ordered without having to do it manually. I have Tried things like makeindex and enumerate, although I have been unable to do what I need with them. Can someone offer advice as to how to do this please?

Comment: glossaries package?

Answer (score 2):

After searching for answers I am able to give myself an answer, you need to use the datatool package, then create a new command and environment, a sortiem command and a sorted list environment, the example I used was from http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8919 this provided the detailed explanation and a working example.